# How to use belongsToMany in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, http, sequelize.js

I'm creating a web app using sequelize to connect to a postgres database. I've managed to teach myself how to use hasMany and belongsTo in order to call, create and destroy data. I'm having trouble with belongsToMany.

In my server I'm trying to create a Trip that belongsToMany Users as riders and added an association for User belongToMany Trip as riders as well. I want to be able to create a trip on a POST request but can't figure out how to call the Ids.

///// MODELS
trip.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Trip = sequelize.define("Trip", {
    driverStart: DataTypes.STRING,
    driverEnd: DataTypes.STRING,
    riderStarts: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
    riderEnds: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
    tripDate: DataTypes.DATE,
    tripHour: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    availableSeats: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    price: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    tripIsActive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  });
  Trip.associate = function(models) {
    Trip.hasMany(models.User, {
      through: "riders_on_trip",
      as: "riders",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "riderIds"
    });
    Trip.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: "driver",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "driverId"
    });
  };
  return Trip;
};
```

user.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    profileImgUrl: DataTypes.STRING,
    fName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lName: DataTypes.STRING,
    yearOfBirth: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    gender: DataTypes.STRING,
    ratings: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER),
      defaultValue: [5]
    },
    onTrip: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    }
  });
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.RideRequest, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "riderId"
    });
    User.hasMany(models.DriveRequest, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "driverId"
    });
    User.hasMany(models.Notification, {
      as: 'sender',
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "senderId"
    });
    User.hasMany(models.Notification, {
      as: 'receiver',
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "receiverId"
    });
    User.belongsToMany(models.Trip, {
      as: "riders",
      through: "riders_on_trip",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "riderIds"
    });
    User.hasMany(models.Trip, {
      as: "driver",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "driverId"
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

///// Controllers

trip.js

```
  create: function create(req,res) {
    // var decodedIds = req.params.riderIds.split("-");
    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    // console.log(decodedIds + '------------------ DECODED IDS ----------------');
    model.User.set
    return model.Trip.create({
      driverStart: req.body.driverStart,
      driverEnd: req.body.driverEnd,
      riderStarts: req.body.riderStarts,
      riderEnds: req.body.riderEnds,
      tripDate: req.body.tripDate,
      tripHour: req.body.tripHour,
      availableSeats: req.body.availableSeats,
      price: req.body.price,
      tripIsActive: req.body.tripIsActive,
      driverId: req.params.driverId,
      riders: [{riderIds: 2}, {riderIds: 2}, {riderIds: 3}]
    }).then(function (trip) {
      console.log(trip.riderIds + '------------ RIDER IDS ---------------');
      return res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Trip created successfully',
        obj: trip
      });
    }).catch(function (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        title: 'Error occured while creating trip',
        error: err
      });
    });
  },
```

Is there any master of programming who could give me a brief explanation on how I could create a trip with this kind of association in sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the hasMany, belongsTo stuff on Trip and User if you are setting up a many to many table. it looks like you set up the many to many table correctly, but if you need to query the trips that belong to a specific user you will need to add another association

```
Trip.belongsToMany(models.User, {
  as: "driver",
  through: "riders_on_trip",
});
```

you get the gist.

you can get the rider ids like this:

```
trip.getRiders().then(function (rider){
    return riders.map((rider) => {
        return rider.id;
    });
)};
```